# convert kaffe to tensorflow - Error: unknown type, unable to resolve "kaffe", IntelliSense may be missing

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe

I copied the convert.py file from https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow for translating caffe files to tensorflow format. I'm not able to Import kaffe. I tried to pip install but couldnt find a Version that satisfied the requirement kaffe.

`Error: unknown type, unable to resolve "kaffe", IntelliSense may be missing`

How can I download or Import this module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, downloading single files from github isn't a good idea. If you aren't able to pip your module, better clone whole repository. Every well documented module has a manual on how to install.

Also, when using pip make sure what is the name of the module in pypi.

PS: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616620/caffe-to-tensorflow-kaffe-by-ethereon-typeerror-descriptors-should-not-be-c) question, maybe it somehow resolves your problem.

Comment: cloning the whole respository solved my Problem! Thx a lot!

Comment: Cool, glad to help!